# Unable to install mongodb on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mongodb

There is an errors when executing,the error as follows.

```
pccs063@pccs063-System-Product-Name:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.14
connecting to: test
Fri May 13 13:03:55.501 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be solved by the below mentioned 5 steps

Step 1: Remove lock file.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

Step 2: Repair mongodb.

```
sudo mongod --repair
```

Step 3: start mongodb.

```
sudo start mongodb
```

or

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

Step 4: Check status of mongodb.

```
sudo status mongodb
```

or

```
sudo service mongodb status
```

Step 5: Start mongo console.

```
mongo
```